# How to classify the style of Guild Wars 2?

Tags: adobe-photoshop, style

I need some photoshop brushes, and I swear I've seen the name of this style before - http://www.guildwars2.com/en/

I absolutely love that grungey/painted style, but no matter what I'm searching in my usual spots for photoshop brushes similar to this, I just can't find what to call it. I know they use the "flourish" technique for a lot of the visual effects. Could anyone point me in the right direction?

Comment: I totally have The Thief wallpaper on my computer right now. I love the art style as well! Would love to know any names :]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I believe the style is called "Ink" or "Ink Brush." It's become quite popular in recent years. I remember seeing it in [Street Fighter 4](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=TuCkpfM2pNo) a while back and it was nicely done.

To achieve it, you can use any of the water color photoshop brushes. Here are some links:

http://www.bittbox.com/freebies/free-hi-res-watercolor-photoshop-brushes

http://designm.ag/resources/watercolor-photoshop-brushes/

http://naldzgraphics.net/freebies/400-free-high-quality-watercolor-brushes-for-photoshop/

Comment: ehm I mean resources of Brushes... i got confused :D